# Where are the "missing" EIPs numbers

Tags: eip, erc

A reference to a (non-existent) ERC715 popped up in a SE question and this made me wonder if there is a rationale behind the [EIP numbering](https://eips.ethereum.org) (based on the eip1, draft are included in the eip process and therefore should have a ref number, then where are the missing ones - eip4 for instance) ?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [EIP-1](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1), the EIP number is assigned from the PR number on the [ethereum repo](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues) **or** can be the Issue number (at the editor discretion, it looks like the latest option is followed nowadays).

Comment: I think that it is actually the **EIP editor** who assigns the EIP number, not the **EIP author**. Quoting from [EIP-1](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1): *Once the EIP is ready for the repository, the EIP editor will assign an EIP number (generally the PR number, but the decision is with the editors)*.

Comment: oh, good catch - edited